# Django Template String Concatenation based on number of non-empty variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two string variables that I want to display on a Django template. If variable a is empty, do not display it. Similar with b. But if a and b are both non-empty, then concatenate the two strings with a ' & '.

Here's the logic in Python.

```py
res = ''
if a != '':
    res = a

if b != '':
    if res == '':
        res = b
    else:
        res = res + ' & ' + b

print(res)
```

How would I write this logic into a Django template?

Comment: IMHO, you should write this logic in view instead of template

Comment: That code can also be shortened to one line: `res = ' & '.join(filter(None, [a, b]))`

Comment: @ruddra I will try it in view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write this logic in view as the comment of @ruddra,
but if you adhere to use django template, you can try this:

```
{% if a == ' ' %}
    {% if b == ' ' %}
        res = ''
    {% else %}
        res = {{b}}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {% if b == ' ' %}
        res = {{a}}
    {% else %}
        res = {{a}} & {{b}}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it's easier to write this in your *view* instead of *template*.

If you really want to:

```
{% if a != '' and b != '' %}
  {{ a }}&amp;{{ b }}
{% elif a != '' and b == '' %}
  {{ a }}
{% elif a == '' and b != '' %}
  {{ b }}
{% else %}
  {# You didn't mention #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res=''
if a !='': 
     if b!='':
          res= a + '&' + b     
     else:
          print('b is empty')
else:
     print('a is empty')

print(res)
```

## if 'res' is empty its print nothing